# SQL Select Data From 3 Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm developing a C# application for a local business. I want to select data from 3 tables of a SQL Server 2014 database, namely `companyinfo`, `invmain`, `invtran`.

`Companyinfo` stores the name of business, `invmain` has sales invoice number and date info while `invtran` has Invoice Transaction.

I'm using a SELECT statement like this:

```
SELECT 
    companyinfo.name,    
    invmain.invno, invmain.date, invtrans.itemid, invtrans.unitprice 
FROM 
    companyinfo, invmain, invtrans
WHERE 
    companyinfo.Id = 1 
    AND invmain.invno = 13 
    AND invtrans.invnumber = 13
```

But this returns null if one of table has no data. Is there any other effective way to do that?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the **proper ANSI/SQL JOIN syntax** like this:

```
SELECT 
    ci.name,    
    invmain.invno, invmain.date, 
    invtrans.itemid, invtrans.unitprice 
FROM 
    companyinfo ci, 
INNER JOIN
    invmain m ON ci.companyId = m.companyId
INNER JOIN
    invtrans it ON it.invo = m.invno
WHERE 
    companyinfo.Id = 1
```

and you need to define **JOIN conditions** between the tables to establish the "links". I've chosen `INNER JOIN` which returns only rows that exist in both tables involved, based on the matching condition defined after the `ON` keyword.

If you want to select rows from `companyinfo` that don't have any corresponding invoices, you could also use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of the `INNER JOIN` to get back data from `companyinfo` for companies without any invoices

Comment: Where the given parameter (invoice Number) will go? 
invmain.invno is Different from invtrans.invnumber
Where are you comparing it wo the parameter that is received? Like say 13.

Comment: @wish568: if you need such a condition, add it to the `WHERE` clause where it belongs

Comment: Thank you so much @marc_s.. This really worked like charm.:)